# How can I create a horizontal line with the pp points above and the reference correspondingly below neatly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

[image: This is the kind of line I intended. I wanted the reference to be stated right below the pp, not slanted as I had ended up coding]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{ctex, hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks,listings,stackengine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric, arrows.meta,chains, arrows.spaced}
\usepackage[overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsopn} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\let\tempItemizeBeg\itemize
\let\tempItemizeEnd\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}{\tempItemizeBeg \justifying}{\tempItemizeEnd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Effect Sizes}
\begin{itemize}
    \item{\scriptsize Mauryama,(2014):Non-coresident parents-higher chance of longevity}
    \item {\scriptsize Varghese and Roy,(2019): Reduces anaemia in pregnant women}
    \item {\scriptsize Anukriti et al.,(2019): Likelihood to Visit HC}
\end{itemize}
%\vspace{-3cm}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % draw horizontal line   
        \draw (-5,0) -- (6,0);
    
    
  
    
    % draw nodes
    \hspace{-1cm}
    \draw (-2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{0}  \textbf{3pp} \end{turn} $};
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{0}\textbf {5.32pp} {$\begin{turn}{45}Mauryama,(2014) \end{turn}$}\end{turn}$};
     \hspace{2.5cm}
    \draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{0}\textbf {(-)13.2pp} {$\begin{turn}{45}Varghese and Roy,(2019) \end{turn}$}\end{turn}$};
     \hspace{2.5cm}
    \draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{0}\textbf {(-)13.4pp} {$\begin{turn}{45}Anukriti et al.,(2019) \end{turn}$}\end{turn}$};
   
           
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't compile your code: `Environment turn undefined. \end{frame}`

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you don't need to load `graphicx`, beamer already loads it and you certainly don't need to load it a second time. Beamer also already loads `hyperref`, `xcolor` and `amsmath`. Instead of `multicol` I would use beamer's own column mechanism. Are you sure `parskip`, `titlesec` and `setspace` are a good idea with beamer?

Comment: If you don't need `ctex` in your example, consider posting an example without it. Much more people will be able to compile if they don't need the special fonts for ctex

Comment: Sorry Im completely new to Latex coding.  Trying to navigate it

Answer (score 0):

- You should really clean up your preamble. In particular if you are new to latex, only load the packages which you use in this document. This will avoid running into problems due to interactions between packages.

  This is even more important if you use the beamer class. Many packages are designed for normal document classes and aren't necessarily a good idea to use with beamer.
- redefining the itemize environment is not the best of ideas. You loose all the extra goodies beamer adds to this environment, like overlay-awareness.
- If you switch font sizes without ending the paragraph, the spacing between lines will be wrong. Instead you can simply set the appropriate beamer font and beamer will change the font size in the itemization for you
- Maybe a tikz introduction would be useful to read. You can find a tutorial at the start of the user guide at https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz/0 . If you prefer books, there is a review of a tikz book in the current TUGBoat: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb44-3/tb138reviews-kottwitz-tikz.pdf

  In short: you can place text in a tikz picture using the simple syntax of `\node at (2,4) {text}`. Tikz can also automatically place such nodes, but if you are a complete beginner, absolute coordinates might be more intuitive.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table}]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\itemize}{\raggedright}{\justifying}{}{}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Effect Sizes}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Mauryama (2014): Non-coresident parents-higher chance of longevity
        \item Varghese and Roy (2019): Reduces anaemia in pregnant women
        \item Anukriti et al. (2019): Likelihood to Visit HC
    \end{itemize}
    
    \vfill
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-3,0) -- (6,0);
        \draw (-2,0.1) -- (-2,-0.1);
        \draw (2,0.1) -- (2,-0.1);
        \node[font=\bfseries,anchor=south] at (-2,0.15) {3pp};
        \node[font=\bfseries,anchor=south] at (2,0.15) {5.32pp};
        \node[anchor=north,text width=3cm,align=center] at (-2,-0.15) {Mauryama (2014)};
        \node[anchor=north,text width=3cm,align=center] at (2,-0.15) {Varghese and Roy (2019)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]